# Using property observers on NSManaged vars

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject, observers

I have a var declared in a class like so:

```
@NSManaged var isFavorite: Bool
```

I would like to declare a property observer, very similar to the one below.

```
 var organization: String {
        didSet { postNotificationWithName( "newData" ) }
    }
```

However, Swift tells me that having property observers on `NSManaged` vars is not allowed. Is there any way I can implement such a feature or something similar for my `isFavorite` variable?

Comment: Do you want to post a notification or support key-value observers, or both? Where does `postNotificationWithName()` come from?

Answer (score 38):

Yes-- delete the `@NSManaged`. It's not absolutely required, but if you delete it you unfortunately need to implement `get` and `set` for the property. You would need to add something like

The `@objc` is only needed if you want to be able to do KVO on the property.

```
@objc public var newData: String? {
    set {
        willChangeValue(forKey: "newData")
        setPrimitiveValue(newValue, forKey: "newData")
        didChangeValue(forKey: "newData")
    }
    get {
        willAccessValue(forKey: "newData")
        let text = primitiveValue(forKey: "newData") as? String
        didAccessValue(forKey: "newData")
        return text
    }
}
```

It's kind of annoying to implement both of these if you don't actually need them but that's the way it is for now.

Since you'll have a `set`, you might not need a `didSet`, but you can still add a `didSet` if you want one.

Comment: The reason I have declared the variable as `NSManaged` is that I require that variable to be cached locally using the Core Data (as a part of Parse's local data store). Is there a way to resolve that?

Comment: Using `@NSManaged` is not necessary when using Core Data if you implement accessors like those in the answer. The code above still saves data to the persistent store.

Comment: Xcode gives me an error that my `Attendee` class doesn't have the members named `setPrimitiveValue` and `didAccessValueForKey`.

Comment: Every class that subclasses `NSManagedObject` implements `setPrimitiveValue(_:,key:)` and `didAccessValueForKey(_:)`. If you're getting those errors then either you're not subclassing `NSManagedObject` or you got the method signature wrong.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution. But the problem is that sometimes it doesn't set the value

Comment: @M090009 If not then there's something wrong with your implementation. You should ask a new question that presents your code in detail.

Comment: Make sure to mark the property with @objc if you want to still be able to do KVO on it.

Comment: Usually, `@NSManaged var isFavorite: Bool` is placed in an extension. If we remove `@NSManaged`, we will get error "Extensions must not contain stored properties". May I know how can we deal with such?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng You deal with it by making it a computed property, using a `get` and `set` block as shown in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get what you mean. But, is there any documentation from Apple which describes such technique. I can find API doc for every individual functions. But, i cant find a documents which integrates all the functions together…

Answer (score 4):

Whoops!  Paul Patterson is right.  What you're supposed to use is Key Value Observing - which is exactly what it says you're supposed to do in the link I suggested.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

See also swift notes:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html
(use the 'On This Page' menu at the top right of the page for Key-Value Observing)

So something like

```
objectToObserve.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "organization", options: .New, context: &myContext)
```

paired with

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the docs you reference explicitly warn you that you shouldn't override this method.

Answer (score -2):

Override `NSManagedObject`'s  `func didChangeValue(forKey key: String)` see (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506976-didchangevalue)

Comment: The documentation clearly says: “You must not override this method.”

Comment: Just ensure that you call the inherited version of this method